# How to create contextual entity relationship diagram in plant uml?

Tags: erd, plantuml

I'm searching from the internet already and it seems I can't find any method to create contextual entity relationship diagram in plant UML like this one:

[image]

So what's lacking from plantUML is the ability to create diamond symbol and create cardinality using number and the letter (N). It seems I can't connect oval to rectangle using multiple lines too.

Comment: By the way, this is an ERD diagram using Chen's notation. Whether it's contextual or not does not seem relevant

Comment: Yeah, I have just realized that, thank you for the correction

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you use `@startdot` you can get a GraphViz diagram. There's an [example](https://graphviz.org/Gallery/neato/ER.html) of what you want to do.

Here's the PlantUML:

```
@startdot
graph ER {
    fontname="Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif"
    node [fontname="Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif"]
    edge [fontname="Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif"]
    layout=neato
    node [shape=box]; course; institute; student;
    node [shape=ellipse]; {node [label="name"] name0; name1; name2;}
        code; grade; number;
    node [shape=diamond,style=filled,color=lightgrey]; "C-I"; "S-C"; "S-I";

    name0 -- course;
    code -- course;
    course -- "C-I" [label="n",len=1.00];
    "C-I" -- institute [label="1",len=1.00];
    institute -- name1;
    institute -- "S-I" [label="1",len=1.00];
    "S-I" -- student [label="n",len=1.00];
    student -- grade;
    student -- name2;
    student -- number;
    student -- "S-C" [label="m",len=1.00];
    "S-C" -- course [label="n",len=1.00];

    label = "\n\nEntity Relation Diagram\ndrawn by NEATO";
    fontsize=20;
}
@enddot
```

[image]

Comment: Cool solution, and it uses PlantUML, but it is really “in” PlantUML?  Or is it really in Graphviz/DOT?

Comment: @AdamMackler ERD isn't really "part of" UML. Dad jokes aside, PlantUML sits on top of DOT, so it's a low-level solution (and there's a slew of Graphviz examples).